# Limit using squeeze law

Tags: calculus

The function $f$ is defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2,&\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\\
0,&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Using the squeeze law, prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0\;.$$

Comment: This is extremely easy; what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

$$0\le f(x)\le x^2\;\ldots..... $$

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site and I'm still trying to work out how to use it. My previous comment was meant to be to someone else. Again, I'm sorry.

Comment: I see @JoeS, no problem: you can erase your unwanted comments just as I have.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we have for $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$, $$\vert f(x) - f(0) \vert < \epsilon$$ $\forall x \in (-\delta, \delta)$.

Comment: I think the OP required to use the squeeze theorem...